# How to get the world globe data in JSON having coordinates (latitude and longitude) with temperature and rainfall information?

Tags: node.js, json, api, leaflet, weather

I am making a project using Leaflet. and i m facing two problems

1) The Leaflet is showing title language of region in there local langauge which i need to show only English title of region.

2) I need a world coordinate data (for each 1 degree of latitude and longitude) of temperature, rainfall information with latitude and longitude information. If anybody helps me to get that JSON file or guide me through which path i can get that file.

Below is some screenshot of project front.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1wIT.png)

using that JSON i will plot the mark location based on the slider information.

I shall be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use another map that contains only English titles.

2) Try this Api: https://openweathermap.org/api/weathermaps

Comment: it this API free to use?

Comment: Is there any way to use english titles, I used this link (https://github.com/buche/leaflet-openweathermap), this link does not have english titles.